# Pytorch model uses GPU memory but volatility at 0

Tags: pytorch

I have a model which takes up gpu memory, but most of the time the GPU is idle and it reaches 90 volatility and then goes back to 0.

How can i maintain volatility to be at 100?

```
class KaggleAmazonDataset(Dataset):
    """Dataset wrapping images and target labels for Kaggle - Planet Amazon from Space competition
    Arguments:
        A CSV file path
        Path to image folder
        Extension of images
        PIL transforms
    """

    def __init__(self, csv_path, img_path, img_ext, transform=None):
        # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        tmp_df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        # assert tmp_df['Left-Fundus'].apply(lambda x: os.path.isfile(img_path + x + img_ext)).all(), \
# "Some images referenced in the CSV file were not found"

        # self.mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.img_ext = img_ext
        self.transform = transform

        self.X_train = tmp_df['Left-Fundus']
        self.y_train = tmp_df.iloc[:, 7:16].values
        # self.y_train = self.mlb.fit_transform(tmp_df['tags'].str.split()).astype(np.float32)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = Image.open(self.img_path + self.X_train[index] + self.img_ext)
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        label = torch.from_numpy(self.y_train[index])
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X_train.index)

# 
transformations = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)),transforms.ToTensor()])

dset_train = KaggleAmazonDataset(TRAIN_DATA,IMG_PATH,IMG_EXT,transformations)
train_loader = DataLoader(dset_train,
                          batch_size=256,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=12, # 1 for CUDA
                         pin_memory=True)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2304, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 8)

    def forward(self, x):

        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) # Flatten layer
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return torch.sigmoid(x)

model = Net().cuda()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.5)
```

Is somthing wrong here, Any suggestions will be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the term `volatility`, did you mean GPU utilization? It seems to me that the data loading process takes too much time so that your GPU has to wait until data is loaded. Have you tried your `Dataloader` with `pin_memory=False`? Depending on your Pytorch version, you might find [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-to-set-pin-memory-to-true/19723/16) thread interesting. Also, in your code block, what do you mean `# 1 for CUDA` in the line of `num_workers=12`? If you are trying to use only 1 worker, batching 256 images can be very slow. You might want to try some smaller batch size and see if your GPU is fully utilized. If your network is small, you do not have to fill all of your GPU memory by increasing batch size.